# Run python code on a folder of XMLs

Tags: python, xml, batch-file, scripting, directory

I would like to be able to run the following code on a folder of XML files rather than a single one. I also do no want to change the `xmlfile = 'test.xml'` line 100+ times for each file.

This is the example `elementTree` code that I found and am testing.

```
from openpyxl import Workbook
import xml.etree.ElementTree as ET

xmlfile = 'test.xml'
element_tree = ET.parse(xmlfile)
root = element_tree.getroot()
agreement = root.find(".//tag").text

print (agreement)

wb = Workbook()
kevin = ["1", "2", "3"]

# grab the active worksheet
ws = wb.active

# Data can be assigned directly to cells
ws['A1'] = 42

# Rows can also be appended
ws.append[(agreement)]
ws.append(kevin)

# Save the file
wb.save("sample.xlsx")
```

Answer (score 0):

Better go with this.

```
import os
import fnmatch
#os.getcwd() or a specific path of the need
path = os.getcwd() + '/open'
mee = [os.path.join(dirpath, f)
    for dirpath, dirnames, files in os.walk(path)
    for f in fnmatch.filter(files, '*.xml')]

for ffile in mee:
    #do other stuff
```